# How to reset service permissions after messing up with `sc sdset`?

Tags: permissions, service, windows

After applying [this "solution"](https://serverfault.com/a/166661/125479) I have no way of starting the spooler service, not even as Admin.

If I open `services.msc` as Administrator, that service has disappeared, [as noted here](https://serverfault.com/q/340752/125479) (I wish I found that before).

How can I reset permissions for the `spooler` service?

Comment: http://systemoverload.net/2010/12/14/how-to-reset-windows-service-sddl-acl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SYSTEM security context can reset it. You don't mention your Windows version, but in Windows Server 2008 and newer versions it can be a bit difficult to get a SYSTEM command prompt. It's very easy, though, to get the "Task Scheduler" in all versions of Windows to run a command as SYSTEM.

- Dump the security descriptor from a known-good machine using the `sc sdshow spooler` command.
- Create a scheduled task on the broken machine to run the command `%SystemRoot%\system32\sc.exe` with the arguments `sdset spoooler <paste good security descriptor here>`.
- Set the task to run as SYSTEM
- Manually run the task

Your service's security descriptor will be restored to normal.

Comment: I found easier [to use `PsExec`](http://cloud.kemta.net/2013/01/resetting-the-discretionary-access-control-list-dacl-in-a-windows-service-security-descriptor/).

The full command was `PsExec.exe /s sc sdset spooler D:(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Evan's Task Scheduler method, I also had to

1. Remove the following registry key (folder)

   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder\Security

[image]

2. Reboot the server